# Can I resolve a generic type from another generic declaration in an interface?

Tags: kotlin

Expect you have an interface like this:

```kotlin
interface MyInterface<T : BaseClass<I>, I> {
    fun someMethod(param: I) : T
}
```

As you can see I use `I` as a parameter in `someMethod`. But actually I don't want to declare `I` when I implement this interface like this:

```kotlin
class BaseClassImpl : BaseClass<OtherClass>

class Impl : MyInterface<BaseClassImpl, OtherClass> {
    override fun someMethod(param: OtherClass) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Theoretically it should be possible that the `I` generic can be resolved by the compiler without the additional declaration because it's provided by `BaseClassImpl`. So `MyInterface<BaseClassImpl>` should already provide enough information to resolve the necessary generic for `someMethod()`.

Is there any way to achieve that in Kotlin?

Comment: Passing partial generics are impossible currently. Its either no-generic or full type-info even in functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossile in Kotlin.
Language specification [states](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-inference.html#type-inference):

> There are two kinds of type inference supported by Kotlin.
>
> - Local type inference, for inferring types of expressions locally, in statement/expression scope;
> - Function signature type inference, for inferring types of function return values and/or parameters.

It can't infer type of one generic parameter based on the type of another (especially for supertype declaration, because it is a very base for building type constrains system).

You may declare typealiases (for each `T`) to avoid repating `I` each time you implement this interface:

```kotlin
typealias MyInterfaceForBaseClassImpl = MyInterface<BaseClassImpl, OtherClass>

class Impl : MyInterfaceForBaseClassImpl {
    override fun someMethod(param: OtherClass) : BaseClassImpl {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The typealias can make it easier when I have to implement a specific combination of this interface multiple times. But actually I will have a lot of different `T` and `I` variations and I guess I need to bite the bullet then.

Answer (score 0):

It is not about compiler resolving, but about enforcing, when you declare `interface MyInterface<T : BaseClass<I>, I : OtherClass>` , declaration expects two parameters, May be you can create `OtherInterface` with OtherClass embedded and use it while implementing instead of `MyInterface`

```kotlin
interface BaseClass<I: OtherClass>
interface OtherClass

interface MyInterface<I : OtherClass, T: BaseClass<I>> {
    fun someMethod(param: I)
}

class BaseClassImpl: BaseClass<OtherClass>

interface OtherInterface<T: BaseClass<OtherClass>> : MyInterface<OtherClass, T>

class Impl : OtherInterface<BaseClassImpl> {
    override fun someMethod(param: OtherClass) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that I had an error in the declaration of the interface. `I` actually don't derive from `OtherClass` but `I` can be any class. Because of that your solution don't solves it since I'd need to declare the intermediate interface for any possible implementation.