# Reference implementing class from interface definition

Tags: java, kotlin, inheritance

Given an interface `I`:

```java
interface I<T> {
    public abstract T doSomthing(T other);
}
```

where any class `C` which implements the interface `I` will always use itself (`C`) as the type parameter:

```java
class MyClass implements I<MyClass> {

    @Override
    public MyClass doSomthing(MyClass other) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without explicitly passing the class `C` as the parameter every time a new class implements the interface?

In other words is it possible, in an interface, to reference the class which implements that interface?

Comment: Is there any language that actually does that? It's verbose for a reason (mostly because it'd create a mess during inheritance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

You asked:

> Is there a way to accomplish this without explicitly passing the class `C`

No, not in Java.

## Example

You seem to be describing exactly the scenario of the [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface bundled with Java. That interface has a single generic argument, for the type of the two objects to be compared. That interface requires a single method [`compareTo​(T o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) taking a single parameter of that same generic type.

Let’s look at an example usage in the OpenJDK source code, [the source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/Year.java) for class [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html).

The class declares itself explicitly as the type of comparison on the `Comparable` interface being implemented.

```java
public final class Year
        implements Temporal, TemporalAdjuster, Comparable<Year>, Serializable {
```

The `compareTo` method explicitly cites its own class as the type being compared.

```java
@Override
    public int compareTo(Year other) {
        return year - other.year;
    }
```

You asked:

> Is there a way to accomplish this without explicitly passing the class C as the parameter every time a new class implements the interface?

It seems the answer is *No*. The implementing class must cite itself explicitly as the fulfillment of the generic type of the interface being implemented.

Caveat: (a) I am not an expert on such language matters. (b) I may have misunderstood your question.

Comment: It's the same in Kotlin, it can't be done, so you're right.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answer: **what you're describing is a *self type*.**

Some other languages have it (such as [Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html)).

But I'm afraid Kotlin doesn't.  (Java [doesn't](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6479372), either.)

There has been [long discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/self-types/371) about the possibility of adding it to a future version of Kotlin; it seems the potential uses may not be wide enough for it to be worthwhile, though there doesn't seem to be a final consensus.

The usual workaround is using a type parameter — similar to what C++ calls [the curiously-recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).  It's not *quite* as typesafe in Java or Kotlin, as this question illustrates, but [covers most of the same ground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52611146/alternatives-to-crtp-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

That's called [self-bounded generics](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=136394). It could be declared in Java as well as in Kotlin.

Java:

```java
interface I<T extends I<T>> {
    public abstract T doSomething(T other);
}
```

Kotlin:

```kotlin
interface I<T : I<T>> {
    fun doSomething(other: T): T
}
```

But it doesn't mean, that generic parameter could be omitted then you declare classes, implementing this interface. It just imposes additional restrictions on type, you're passing as a generic parameter (narrowing it down to only one type). Type inference is not supported for class declaration neither in Kotlin, nor in Java.

Also see: [Can I resolve a generic type from another generic declaration in an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66258998/can-i-resolve-a-generic-type-from-another-generic-declaration-in-an-interface/66261497#66261497)